# Adding a certain amount of values from an Array to a Collection View

Tags: swift, swift3

I have an Array of UIImages that I add to a Collection View with 40 cells. I want to use an integer to choose the amount of UIImages that is taken from that Array and add a default UIImage to the remaining cells.

(If the Integer is 7 I want to take 7 UIImages from the Array and use the default UIImage  at the remaining 33 cells)

This is how I currently add image by image to the cells.

```
cell.imageView?.image = imageArray[indexPath.row]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `cellForItem(at:)`:

```
if indexPath.item >= 7 {
    cell.imageView?.image = defaultImage
} else {
    cell.imageView?.image = imageArray[indexPath.item]
}
```

You can replace the `7` with a property of your `UICollectionView` subclass and then check that.

Comment: Works perfectly !

Answer (score 1):

replace this line:

`cell.imageView?.image = imageArray[indexPath.row]`

with:

`cell.imageView?.image = ((myInteger > indexPath.row) ?
 imageArray[indexPath.row] : myDefaultImage)`

where `myDefaultImage` is your default image and `myInteger` is your magic number